# Custom TimerDialog Titanium appcelerator android

Tags: android, titanium

I creating a application for android smartphones using Titanium appcelerator.

- I need to show the time dialog which having 5 minutes interval.
  How could i specify the time interval in timer dialog..I was getting 1 min interval now..

  ***Reference***:[Sample ref Link in native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214547/show-timepicker-with-minutes-intervals-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

There is !CURRENTLY! no way to do it "easy" because the "minuteInterval" attribute you want is only available for IOS.

The solution, as you link it, is to create your own date&time picker. which will up & down from 1 to 5.