# Custom TimePicker

Tags: android, android-custom-view, timepicker

I want to create a custom TimePicker with a 15-minute interval. I found a lot of resources around the Internet showing examples about custom TimePickerDialog.

I don't have any idea about how to implement a custom TimePicker. For the moment, I have this in my XML layout:

```
<TimePicker 
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and I instantiate it in my Java this way:

```
tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

There are many questions I'm asking myself:

1. What must I do to get a CustomTimePicker? Is extending Android's native TimePicker enough?
2. What methods must be overridden to implement the 15-minute interval?
3. If I manage to get my CustomTimePicker, how to declare it in my XML, since Android's parser won't understand a `<CustomTimePicker />` tag?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214547/show-timepicker-with-minutes-intervals-in-android

Comment: @shkschneider: I've already seen this post, but, as said above, it concerns a TimePickerDialog, not a TimePicker. Plus it doesn't say anything about what to do with the newly created CustomTimePickerDialog so as to display it in an activity.

Comment: @RichouHunter undelete your other question please http://stackoverflow.com/q/23342318