# change braces position with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have multiple source codes in which braces are like this

```
function()
{
    if(...)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to make it look like this:

```
function() {
    if(...) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried some tricks with the `sed` command, but I can't figure out how to get it working properly. Here is my latest try:

```
sed ":a; N; $!ba; s/\n{/ {/g" myfile
```

EDIT -

I managed to have this working with that command:

```
sed "N;/\n *{/s// {/;P;D"
```

As usual with `sed`, I quite don't understand why it works, but it does.

Comment: No, no, _please_ don't use regular expressions for this.

Comment: @devnull: Why? Aren't regexes exactly the thing I need to spot those braces down?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're performing code formatting, can I suggest you use a tool more geared to this, and investigate something like [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). Here's the info for your [specific issue](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Bracket_Style_Options) (brace positioning)

Comment: Ok, I need to compile it by myself. I'll take a closer look to it tonight. Thanks. :)