# Limit Android Time Picker to Business Hours

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm using a TimePicker to allow a user to select a scheduled time slot during a business day. For example the user could use the TimePicker to schedule a meeting at 8:00am, 8:30am, 9:30am , etc... all the way to 8:00pm. Based on the response from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396673/950953 I've managed to limit the minute picker to two options of 0 and 30. However, I cannot figure out how to limit the hour picker to start at 8am and end at 8pm. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using `TimePicker` you could use two `NumberPicker`s which would allow you to set min and max on the hour. Although, I would think if you were able to set the minute options then you should be able to also set the hour options. I've only used `NumberPicker` in the past.

Comment: Rather than set min and max (which wouldn't work too well with time (non-24hr format), with a `NumberPicker` you can set the values that get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know proper way, but if you don't find anything you can try something like:

Set picker to e.g. 8:00, and you can get moment when user start scrolling with `setOnTimeChangedListener (TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener onTimeChangedListener)`

In that listener check if user was scrolling up or down, and manually set the picker let's say 8:30. It will still be shitty, because within picker user will se minutes ascending by 1, but he will scroll for 30 minutes.