# How to set Android TimePicker with 5 minutes interval (Nougat)

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-timepicker

I am using Android 7.0 (Nougat)
I create EditText to display time, when click it, it will show a TimePicker, and update time in EditText
Everything works smoothly, but now I want to show a Timepicker with 5 minutes interval
It means that user only can select 5,10,15,20...minutes
Here is my code:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

private EditText mEditText;
private int initHour;
private int initMinute;

public void setEditText(EditText editText) {
    mEditText = editText;
}

public void setInitHour(int hour) {
    initHour = hour;
}

public void setInitMinute(int minute) {
    initMinute = minute;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, initHour, initMinute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    SimpleDateFormat timeSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    mEditText.setText(timeSdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

}

And in Activity:

```
TimePickerFragment dialogFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
dialogFragment.setInitHour(11);
dialogFragment.setInitMinute(30);
dialogFragment.setEditText(mStartTimeText);
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "startTimePicker");
```

I've researched related posts, but all the solutions are not up-to-date
I cannot find a solution fitting for Nougat version
If any hint for me, I will very appreciate! Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214547/show-timepicker-with-minutes-intervals-in-android?rq=1

@Yuan Did you check this ?

Comment: Hey did you find anything.?

Answer (score 0):

TimePicker doesn't support intervals. You will have to implement  custom view to achieve that functionality.
Copy paste solution ;) . You are welcome.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import android.widget.TimePicker
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.util.*


    class TimePickerInterval @JvmOverloads constructor(
            context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : TimePicker(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
        private var MINUTE_INTERVAL = 1
        override fun getCurrentMinute(): Int {
            return super.getCurrentMinute() * MINUTE_INTERVAL
        }
    
        override fun getMinute(): Int {
            return super.getMinute() * MINUTE_INTERVAL
        }
    
        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow()
            setUp()
        }
    
        private fun setUp() {
            try {
                val classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R\$id")
                val field: Field = classForid.getField("minute")
                val mMinuteSpinner = findViewById<NumberPicker>(field.getInt(null))
                mMinuteSpinner.minValue = 0
                mMinuteSpinner.maxValue = 60 / MINUTE_INTERVAL - 1
                val displayedValues: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
                var i = 0
                while (i < 60) {
                    displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i))
                    i += MINUTE_INTERVAL
                }
                mMinuteSpinner.displayedValues = displayedValues.toTypedArray()
    
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    
        override fun setOnTimeChangedListener(onTimeChangedListener: OnTimeChangedListener) {
            super.setOnTimeChangedListener { tp, hour, minute ->
                onTimeChangedListener.onTimeChanged(tp, hour, minute * MINUTE_INTERVAL)
            }
        }
    
        override fun setMinute(minute: Int) {
            super.setMinute(minute/MINUTE_INTERVAL)
        }
    
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            @BindingAdapter("time_picker_set_minute_interval")
            fun setInterval(view: TimePickerInterval, interval: Int?) {
                interval?.let {
                    view.MINUTE_INTERVAL = interval
                    view.setUp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In your XML:

```
<com.gixon.shared.widgets.TimePickerInterval
    android:id="@+id/tp_to"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    time_picker_set_minute_interval="@{5}"
    />
```