# How to give validation to calendar

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I'm creating a appointment booking app in android studio.
So while selecting time in time picker i want the time between 14:00pm and 16:00pm to be disabled ,similarly - the timing at night must be disabled.
&
While selecting Date , I want the previous dates to be disabled.
is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything, any sample code or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a custom TimePickerDialog in this case, same goes to the date as well if you would need that functionality too.

See this post - [Custom TimePickerDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396673/4206951) or use this library - [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) with material design.