# TimePicker with Spinners?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, timepickerdialog

I'm trying to build a TimePickerDialog but unfortunately the Time Picker that comes up is extremely cumbersome to Use :

[image]

Is there any way to build a timepicker like the old ones that Android use to have like below :

[image]

My code is as follows :

```
    ButtonTime.Click += delegate
    {
        ShowTimePickerDialog();
    };

    void ShowTimePickerDialog()
    {
        var dialog = new TimePickerDialogFragment(this, hour, minute, this);

        dialog.Show(FragmentManager, null);
    }
```

Comment: The first one is infinitely nicer looking than that gawd awful spinner monstrosity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say use the Holo theme.
I refer to following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773646/can-we-display-old-style-time-picker-pre-lollipop-time-picker-in-lollipop-dev) on stackoverflow which you might find usefull.

Comment: Nice that did it. I'm using the holo theme.

Comment: Now quick question how can I set the timepickermode programmatically in a timepickerdialog

Comment: You could achieve this by passing a defStyleRes or maybe a defStyleAttr when you create your time picker.

Answer (score 7):

adding new xml style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="SpinnerTimePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ClockTimePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

than set the timepicker style to SpinnerTimePicker in MainTheme

```
 <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerTimePicker</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

android:timePickerMode
Defines the look of the widget. Prior to the L release, the only choice was spinner. As of L, with the Material theme selected, the default layout is clock, but this attribute can be used to force spinner to be used instead.

Must be one of the following constant values.

Constant    Value   Description
clock   2   Time picker with clock face to select the time.
spinner 1   Time picker with spinner controls to select the time.

from Documentaion

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#attr_android:timePickerMode